# Component not showing in frontend on Joomla! 1.7

Tags: plugins, components, frontend, backend, joomla1.7

I have successfully installed a plugin called "Plotalot", which draws flashcharts, on my Joomla! 1.7.

I have unfortunately installed the free version of it because I want to be sure it's useful, and the free version comes with the component-tool only and not with the plugin (It's cheap, but I hate purchasing stuff that's not worth using).

With the component-tool on the **backend** site I'm able to create new charts, edit existing charts and I'm also capable of seeing a demonstration of the chart that I just made on the backend site.

But, when I try to see the chart on the **frontend** site, I only see the tags which I wrote in an Article and no chart. In this case: **{plotalot id="1"}**

I've been in touch with this customer support guy on this matter, and all he can say is that it should be a chart when i write **{plotalot id="1"}** if there's a chart with the ID=1. Which it does

Does anyone have any experience on how plugins or component-tools in Joomla! 1.7 works and how they can be displayed in an Article?
I would very much appreciate if someone can help me :)

Kind regards, Steve-O

Comment: Solved it! Apparently, this type of components like Plotalot, you have to create a menu item of the type "Simple List of charts" and add it to whatever menu that's pleasent. And it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also a Plotalot user. Your question does not make sense. If you installed the free version, you did not install a plugin, you installed a component. Plotalot does not draw flash charts, it draws Google charts. If you want a chart in an article, buy the plugin. And read the user guide, it explains all of this very clearly.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use some tags in the article in which you want to display the charts.The tags will be explained in the documentation of the plug in 
eg:we use {flashchart data="50,60,70,80,90,60|109,120,100,130,140,100"} sample01{/flashchart}
to display flash chart.